# C++Concepts: How to enforce a method to accept a constrained type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

If I want to specify what is the interface of a template parameter, I would do it this way:

```cpp
template<typename T>
requires requires (T t, int i)
{
    { T(i) };
    { t.test() } -> std::same_as<bool>;
    { t.result() } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>;
}
struct Foo
{ // ...
};
```

I do not know however how to describe a situation where `T` should have a function that is templated (with some constraints).

```cpp
struct tmplt
{
    template<std::integral T>
    void bar(T t);
};

template<typename T>
requires requires (T t)
{
    { t.bar(*) };
}
struct Foo
{ // ...
};
```

What should I put instead of `*` so that I get the desired effect (saying *`bar` is callable with `std::integral` parameter*)?

Comment: Why does it matter? Are you going to call it with *any* or *all* integral type?  Just check against the type you *intend* to call it with. If `bar`'s constraint isn't satisfied, your requirement won't be either.

Comment: You have to manually spell every type you want to pass.